# AngularJs app does not bind data to DOM

Tags: angularjs

I have created simple angularJS app.I used ng-repeat to bind data to DOM

```
  <div class="row folder" ng-repeat="f in viewModel.folders">
    <div>{{f.name}}</div>
    </div>
```

so weird ,my data not bind to DOM until I click any button with "ng-click" action.
I do not know why ?

Comment: I'm going to assume `viewModel.folders` is an async operation that is outside of the Angular runloop. In which case you'll need to `$scope.apply()` after assigning your data to `viewModel.folders`.

Comment: thank to Wildhoney,I resolved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved myself by call $scope.apply() at the end.